# Numerical integration problem: IntegrationWarning The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent

Tags: python, numerics, scipy, integration

I am trying to get the numerical integration of a function using `scipy's integrate.quad` as follows.

$$
\begin{equation}
G (\alpha) = \frac{4\alpha}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-\alpha x^2} {(\pi/2}+\mathrm{tan}^{-1}[Y_0(x)/J_0 (x)]) \mathrm{d}x 
\end{equation}
$$

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.special import k0,j0,y0,k1
def G(alpha=743711.5,T=5.5e-5,sw=10.65):
    pi = 3.14
    fun = lambda x: x*np.exp(-1*alpha*x**2)*(pi/2+np.arctan(y0(x)/j0(x)))
    val,err = integrate.quad(fun,0, np.inf)
    return val,err
val,err = G()
print (val,err)
```

However, I get "The integral is probably divergent, or slowly convergent."
I have tried to set a very large limit, such as `limit = 10000000`. However, the same warning is. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

https://doi.org/10.1029/TR033i004p00559
[image: Edit: adding equation source]

Comment: Should $x$ be $u$ in that arctan function?

Comment: Please make sure the question is correctly formulated. Do you integrate over $u$ or over $x$?

Comment: Thank you. After I read the cited reference (Smith, 1937), I have found there are some errors in the above pasted source paper, and I have assured that the intergration is over x.  I have corrected the above equation and code. However, the same warning is there.

Comment: Have you tried to split the integral at the sum? I feel like the first summand could have an analytical solution, simplyfing the task and numerical effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the value of $\alpha$ is large compared to the values of $x^2$ that the numerical integrator is probably choosing. For any value $x \gg 1/\sqrt{\alpha}$ the integrand will be close to zero (for large enough values it will be exactly zero in floating point). The integrand is also zero at $x = 0$. So there is no point in setting the limit to a large value. On the contrary, try setting it to something like $10/\sqrt{\alpha}, 20/\sqrt{\alpha}, ...$ and check for convergence of the results.

Perhaps best would be to define a new variable $u = x/\sqrt{\alpha}$ and integrate with respect to $u$. Then the numerical integrator should probably work.

Comment: in addition the first integral has an analytical solution, so they could remove this first.